# The C Programming Language (K&R) - Exercise 1-13

Tags: c

Relatively new to programming here, and I'm attempting to make my way through the second edition of K&R's "The C Programming Language." I've got the answer book to the exercises, and I got horribly stuck on Exercise 1-13, so I took a look at it to get an idea.

The task is this: "Write a program to print a histogram of the lengths of words in its input. It is easy to draw the histogram with the bars horizontal; a vertical orientation is more challenging."

And the code given in the answer book is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXHIST 15  
#define MAXWORD 11  
#define IN 1        
#define OUT 0      


main()
{

    int c, i, nc, state;
    int len;
    int maxvalue;
    int ovflow;
    int wl[MAXWORD];

    state = OUT;
    nc = 0;         
    ovflow = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < MAXWORD; i++)
        wl[i] = 0;  

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if(c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
        {
            state = OUT;            
            if (nc > 0)
            {
                if (nc < MAXWORD)   
                    ++wl[nc];       
                else
                    ++ovflow;       
            }                       
            nc = 0;                 
        }
        else if (state == OUT)
        {
            state = IN;             
            nc = 1;                 
        }
        else
            ++nc;                   
    }

    maxvalue = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < MAXWORD; ++i)
    {
        if(wl[i] > maxvalue)
            maxvalue = wl[i];       
    }

    for(i = 1; i < MAXWORD; ++i)
    {
        printf("%5d - %5d : ", i, wl[i]);
        if(wl[i] > 0)
        {
            if((len = wl[i] * MAXHIST / maxvalue) <= 0)
                len = 1;
        }
        else
            len = 0;

        while(len > 0)
        {
            putchar('*');
            --len;
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    if (ovflow > 0)
        printf("There are %d words >= %d\n", ovflow, MAXWORD);

    return 0;

}
```

I can understand the vast majority of it, but this particular section is giving me trouble:

```
for(i = 1; i < MAXWORD; ++i)
{
    printf("%5d - %5d : ", i, wl[i]);
    if(wl[i] > 0)
    {
        if((len = wl[i] * MAXHIST / maxvalue) <= 0)
            len = 1;
    }
    else
        len = 0;

    while(len > 0)
    {
        putchar('*');
        --len;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Now, I understand that the if function `if((len = wl[i] * MAXHIST / maxvalue) <= 0)` is normalising the values in the array. What I don't understand is that it sets `len = 1`. If `len` is always `1`, shouldn't the `putchar('*')` function only print one asterisk for any given value above 0?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The only time that the program flow reaches to `len = 1;` is when the denominator `maxvalue` becomes greater than numerator `wl[i] * MAXHIST ` due to the high frequency of a particular word length. `a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a so` (16 words with the length of 1 and one word with the length of 2) is an example of that situation.

Answer (score 1):

The condition

```
if((len = wl[i] * MAXHIST / maxvalue) <= 0)
        len = 1;
```

Will never actually be less than zero since it is only applied to positive `wl[i]`. As you supposed, `len` is being normalized to a maximum number of asterisks. Notice that in the `if` statement itself, `(len = wl[i] * MAXHIST / maxvalue)`. So `len` is just normalized. Only if the normalization truncates to zero (because that is what integer division does to numbers less than 1), will `len` be set to `1`. This just ensures that at least one asterisk will be printed for the non-zero bars.

Answer (score 1):

It's saying this:

If we have a non-zero word length, but the normalized value is 0, we want to distinguish it from 0 by bumping it up to 1. Otherwise we use the normalized value (which is set in the if-statement itself -- not a good practice by most modern coding standards).

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to separate this `if` into to parts.

```
len = wl[i] * MAXHIST / maxvalue;
if (len <= 0)
    len = 1;
```

Now it should be clear that `len` will be set to 1 only if its calculated value is not greater than 0.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. There's another little thing confusing me, though. Why does the else statement set `len` to `0`? I may just be being a little dense here, but it seems like len will always be set to either 0 or 1?

Comment: @arevans, no, not always. If `wl[i]` is greater than 0, then `len` will be calculated. If it is below 0, len will become 1. Finally if `wl[i]` is 0, `len` will be 0. You might want to pick each of the cases (say -1, 0, 1) and manually go through the code to see what happens

Comment: Ah, I'm seeing it now! It certainly is easier to set `len` outside the if-statement. I was reading it as a single, separate condition inside the statement, rather than a variable assignment and a subsequent test. Thanks very much!